How to I select the records only when I click on the button?
I am using Airtable blocks to create an extension. I have a button that, when pressed, should retrieve the records. However, I am not able to get it to run when the button is clicked...only when the button is loaded. I only want it to run when clicked since I have a lot of tables and loading all the records from all the tables at once could be overkill. How do I get it to run only when I press the button? The error I get is Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Without the
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import { useBase, useRecords, Button } from "@airtable/blocks/ui";
 
 function getRecords(Item) {
   const base = useBase();
   const table = base.getTableIfExists(Item.table);
   return useRecords(table);
 }
 
 export default function RunButton({ Item }) {
   // This works but will potentially load a LOT of data
   const records = getRecords(Item);
   records.map((record) => {
     console.log(record.id);
   });
 
   // This errors
   function onClick() {
     const records = getRecords(Item);
     records.map((record) => {
       console.log(record.id);
     });
   }
 
   return (
     <Button size="small" icon="play" onClick={onClick}>
       Run
     </Button>
   );
 }


React hooks can only be called at the top-level or in other custom react hooks. In other words, useBase and useRecords can't be called in a nested function or callback function. I've never heard of this library you are using, but based on their documentation it doesn't appear theres a way to imperatively fetch data. From what I see the hooks are meant to be called normally, e.g. like your "This works but will potentially load a LOT of data" part. I don't think this library will work like you are trying to use it.

FWIW other data query libraries that use hooks allow for skip tokens/etc as part of an options configuration that is also passed to the hook to allow conditional fetching/query execution, or return lazy trigger functions to be called in handlers.

The error occurs because hooks like useBase and useRecords can only be called at top level of function component not inside other function or event handlers like onClick.You should call then at top of your RunButton component and use like this:
const base = useBase();
  const table = base.getTableIfExists(Item.table);

  async function onClick() {
    const records = await table.selectRecordsAsync();
    records.records.map(record => {
      console.log(record.id);
    });
  }


useBase and useRecords seems like are custom hooks (which may include native React hooks). You mustn't call a hook conditionally, such as in a event/callback function.
Try removing
const records = getRecords(Item);

from the onClick function. The content of records should update automatically when Item is changed. You don't need to call it the second time.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useBase, useRecords, Button } from "@airtable/blocks/ui";

function getRecords(Item) {
  const base = useBase();
  const table = base.getTableIfExists(Item.table);
  return useRecords(table);
}

export default function RunButton({ Item }) {
  const records = getRecords(Item);
  records.map((record) => {
    console.log(record.id);
  });

  function onClick() {
    // remove this line, everything should work the same
    // const records = getRecords(Item);
    records.map((record) => {
      console.log(record.id);
    });
  }

  return (
    <Button size="small" icon="play" onClick={onClick}>
      Run
    </Button>
  );
}

